# Can I use "sql-like" queries with XML in VB.Net

Tags: xml, vb.net

Can I select nodes based on criteria by passing queries similar to SQL such as LIKE, CONTAIN,SUM etc in XML?

This is my data structure

```
<institutions>
<institution type="university" abbrv="absu" name="Abia State University (absu)" />
  <institution type="university" abbrv="atbu" name="Abubakar Tafawa Balewa University (atbu)" />
  <institution type="university" abbrv="achievers" name="Achievers University (achievers)" />
<institutions>
```

I want to be able to get institutions using LIKE and other keywords. Can i get the equivalent of the below statement for xml?

SELECT Institution FROM tblInstitutions WHERE Name LIKE '%Abia%'

Comment: Can you explain in more detail, for example what your database looks like and what you want to achieve (result of the queries)? Also the which brand of database you are working on (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgress etc.) is necessary for a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> using XML as a database

Use `System.Xml.Linq` namespace features

```vb
  Dim data As XElement =
     <institutions>
        <institution type="university" abbrv="absu" name="Abia State University (absu)"/>
        <institution type="university" abbrv="atbu" name="Abubakar Tafawa Balewa University (atbu)"/>
        <institution type="university" abbrv="achievers" name="Achievers University (achievers)"/>
     </institutions>

'Search entries where `name` contains "Abia"
Dim result As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = 
    From institution As XElement In data.<institution>
    Where institution.@name.Contains("Abia")
    Select institution
```

Use another LINQ methods `Sum`, `Avg` etc. [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)
Check also XML literals in vb.net [XML Literals Overview (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384629.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the tip bro... But how can i replace the XElement object with a dymanic value?

Comment: `data` is your dynamic value

Comment: I mean how do i poplate it from the xml file

Comment: Use `XDocument.Load(filename)` - [XDocument.Load Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181(v=vs.110).aspx). Create a new question if you want to ask something not exactly related to the current question/answer